# ¿Como puedo ejecutar varias funciones a la vez?

Tags: c, funciones

Necesito ejecutar todas las operaciones anteriormente listadas de una vez, es decir suma, resta, multiplicacion, division y factorial del primer numero con solo elegir la opcion; es decir, **sin salir del `switch`**. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Vuelvo a repetir el codigo de cada una, o hay una manera resumida que no sea tan desprolija y repetitiva?

Comment: Aunque te he entendido, sería recomendable que editaras la pregunta. Lo de `de una vez` confunde mas que otra cosa.

Comment: Primero que nada si vas a ejecutar todas, no necesitas un switch, puedes ejecutarlas una tras otra y puedes guardar el resultado en diferentes variabales.

Comment: @M.Gress lo que quiere es ejecutar la `8` **sin salir del `switch`**. Lo que pasa es que no se ha explicado muy bien que digamos.

Comment: @M.Gress Últimamente son mas importantes nuestras cualidades de *adivino* que las de *programador* jeje

Comment: Jajaja si bastante para entender algunas preguntas.

Comment: De momento, voto por cerrarla: *no está claro lo que se pregunta*.

Comment: Yo creo que en sí. no generaría problemas por que aunque se guarda en result, toma los parametros numero uno y numero 2 como argumentos sin cambiarlos, asi que si lo que haces es reimprimir el valor por cada caso no debe haber problemas. yo veo dos soluciones. o haces un if condicional junto con un for si el numero es 8, y asi llamas al switch 7 veces para que llame a cada caso una vez, o puedes dentro del caso 8 llamar a las funciones, otra vez, o incluso puedes colocar el caso 8 al principio del switch y un condicional del break en cada caso.. saludos

Comment: Pues me parece bastante clara la pregunta si leen el codigo, que es bastante sencillo, y mi pregunta.

Tengo que ejecutar todas las operaciones juntas, como establece la opcion 8

printf("8- Calcular todas las operaciones\n");

es decir, suma resta multiplicacion division y factorial de A con solo apretar un boton, o sea, elegir la opcion 8 y no hacerlas una por una, o sea, elegir 3, luego 4, luego 5, etc.

Comment: pues si bien, la pregunta "_se puede entender_" en realidad no es **bastante clara** lo que se quiere @bornlivedie es que la pregunta sea util no solo para resolver tu problema, para evitar su cierre, lo que mejor puedes hacer es tratar de hacer mas clara la pregunta y ayudarnos a ayudarte y que tu ayudes al que entre a ver tu pregunta. sencillo no? la pregunta podria ser _¿como acceder a varias casos de un switch eligiendo una sola opción?_ el titulo que pones ahora me sonó mas como los hilos de java y multitarea del procesador

Comment: Aclara tu problema específico o añade detalles adicionales para destacar con exactitud lo que necesitas. porque a mi se me ocurren por lo menos tres formas de resolver tu problema, pero si no das las condiciones de lo que necesitas.. si debes usar o no un switch,, por ejemplo etc.. da un contexto. Gracias

Answer (score 6):

Si amigo eso te generara problemas porque se va a reescribir su contenido te recomiendo que crees otras variables para los otros resultados 
Ejemplo:

```
int x,y,result,result2,result3,result4,result5,result6;

 case 3:
    result = suma(x,y);
    printf("RESULTADO SUMA: %d\n",result);
    break;
case 4:
    result = resta(x,y);
    printf("RESULTADO RESTA: %d\n",result2);
    break;
case 5:
    result = dividir(x,y);
    printf("RESULTADO DIVISION: %d\n",result3);
    break;
case 6:
    result = multiplicar(x,y);
    printf("RESULTADO MULTIPLICACION: %d\n",result4);
    break;
case 7:
    result = factorial(x);
    printf("RESULTADO FACTORIAL: %d\n",result5);
    break;
case 8:
    printf("RESULTADO GLOBAL: %d\n",result6);
```

Esto fue lo que yo hice cuando me paso eso ami.

Answer (score 1):

Es  sencillo, una vez que comprendes lo que es un `switch( )`: un `switch( )` es **un simple `goto`**, *endulzado*, y con algún que otro *extra*.

```
int num1 = 0,
    num2 = 0;

switch( opcion ) {
case 1:
  printf( "Ingrese el primer número:\n" );
  scanf( "%d", &num1 );
  break;

case 2:
  printf( "Ingrese el segundo número:\n" );
  scanf( "%d", &num2 );
  break;

case 8:

case 3:
  printf( "Suma: %d\n", suma( num1, num2 ) );
  if( opcion == 3 )
    break;

case 4:
  printf( "Resta: %d\n", resta( num1, num2 ) );
  if( opcion == 4 )
    break;

case 5:
  printf( "Multiplicación: %d\n", multiplica( num1, num2 ) );
  if( opcion == 5 )
    break;

case 6:
  if( !num2 )
    printf( "NO se puede dividir entre 0.\n" );
  else
    printf( "Division: %d\n", divide( num1, num2 ) );

  if( opcion == 6 )
    break;

case 7:
  printf( "Factorial: %d\n", factorial( x ) );
  break;
};
```

Como ves, **no es necesario** que las etiquetas estén **ordenadas**, ni que todas las etiquetas hagan algo. **Tampoco** es obligatorio el `break`. Y, lo que es mas *chulo*: ¡ El `break` puede estar en un condicional !

Answer (score 0):

Podrías checar este código y darle al usuario elegir que desea hacer

```
#include stdio.h
#include math.h

int main(){

    int x;

    double num;
    char sn[1];

    sn[0]='s';

    while((sn[0]=='s')|| (sn[0]=='S'))
    {
        printf("\n (1) El triple  ");

        printf("\n (2) El cuadrado)");

        printf("\n (3) Logaritmo natural");

        printf("\n (4) Logaritmo decimal ");

        printf("\n (5) seno ");

        printf("\n (6) coseno");

        printf("\n Elige una opcion");

        scanf("%d",&x);

switch(x){
    case 1:
        printf("\n\n Escribe el numero:");
        scanf("%lf",&num);
        printf("El triple  de %lf es %lf",num,3*num);
    break;
    case 2:
        printf("\n\n Escribe el numero:");
        scanf("%lf",&num);
        printf("\n el cuadrado de %lf es %lf",num,num*num);
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("\n\n Escribe el número: ");
        scanf("%lf",&num);
        printf("\n El logaritmo neperiano de %lf es %lf ",num,log(num));
    break;
    case 4:
        printf("\n\n Escribe el número: ");
        scanf("%lf",&num);
        printf("\n El logaritmo decimal de %lf es %lf", num,log10(num));    
    break;  
    case 5:
        printf("\n\n Escribe el número: ");
        scanf("%lf",&num);

        printf("\n\n El seno de %lf es %lf ",num,sin(num));
    break;
    case 6:
            printf("\n\n Escribe el número: ");
        scanf("%lf",&num);
        printf("\n\n El coseno de %lf es %lf ",num,cos(num));
        break;
    default:
        printf("\n\n Esto no es ninguna opcion");
        break;
    }

printf("\n\n quieres volver a realizar una operacion (S/N) ");
scanf("%s",sn);
    }
}
```